# Convert SVG file to Autodesk Viewer svf format

Tags: svg, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are looking at using the Forge Viewer for a project to display and markup plans, etc. (for now just 2D, 3D may be added in the future).  For some of these items we will have DWG Files that we can convert using model derivative API so no problem there.  However, the client also has quite a few existing drawings saved in svg format from their legacy system.

The question is if there is a good way to convert those base svg files into svf that we can display as the 'main' drawing/view in Forge Viewer.  I have found things about creating a markup layer from an svg file, but that's not really what we want.  We would be using markups to have the user draw on top of the plan with their own tools and place markers, etc. but the main drawing should be from the svg file that they have.

Forgive me if this is simple but I'm fairly new to the viewer and model derivative API so I'm not figuring out how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [translation support](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/) for **SVG**, to generate an **SVF** model out of it.
You could either 
a) use the **SVG** inside a format that we support (e.g. **DWG** - perhaps place the **SVG** in it using [Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/)) and translate that to **SVF** 
b) load a dummy model as shown [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/simulate-empty-view-forge-viewer), and then add the **SVG** as e.g. markup